# unique persistence of hierarchical object structure

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I have an algorithm which samples models from a space of feasible models. A model is basically a formula so some hierarchical object structure. I would like to persist each model in a database if it is not already persisted. What are my options to find a model very fast when I query the database? I understand that I can use Criteria and an example model to determine whether the model is already in the database. Is there a faster way? This is my first attempt of the model structure:

```
public class Network
{
    public virtual double Bias { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<RBF> RBFs { get; set; }
}

public class RBF
{
    public virtual double Weight { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Gaussian> Gaussians { get; set; }
}

public class Gaussian
{
    public virtual int FeatureIndex { get; set; }
    public virtual double Mean { get; set; }
    public virtual double StandardDeviation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We need more information about how you are structuring the data in code. Once you have whatever you want to persist represented in code as objects that connect to each other, persisting it and making that fast is much more possible. But without knowing more about what you are working with, it's hard to really help. Also, depending on what you mean by "fast", persisting to the DB may not be fast enough and a cached, in-memory element may be needed.

Comment: what do you consider equality of models? `Network.Weight` equals or the whole tree equals?

Comment: Equality is defined by structure and parameters but order does not matter

Comment: How about creating the Primary Key of the persistent model as a function of the model's parameters? That way to check if a model is already persisted, you just run it's parameters through the function and query the database by the primary key? That should be very fast. Of course, the function has be such that it produces unique values for different combinations of parameters. Some sort of hash function should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way, for such a complex equality rule, could to use an algorithm to transform the graph of objects into a String or byte array, to hash this string or byte array using a cryptographic hash function (SHA1, for example), and to store the hash along with the root of the tree.

When you have to check if a given tree already exits in the database, reapply the algorithm on the tree, and check if the obtained hash already exists in database.

The difficulties are the following:

- two logically equal trees must always generate the same byte array. This means that you must decide on an order for your RBFs and Gaussian entities and always serialize them in the same order
- comparing doubles is usually not an easy task. You'll perhaps have to round them to make sure two very close values are considered equal
- you have to recompute the hash each time a modification is made on any of the entities composing the tree. This means that all the changes should be encapsulated in a single place and always go through the root of the tree.

Comment: I kind of realise now that what I try to do is more or less impossible (canonicalising trees). The algorithm would have to determine that ( sqrt(2) + sqrt(7 - 3*sqrt(5)) ) /  sqrt(3 - sqrt(5)) is in fact identically equal to sqrt(5) (just a related example). I will accept your answer though.